# ajax datatable make link on row

Tags: ajax, datatables

I'm passing data to datatable

```
$records["data"][] = array(
                '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'">',
                $id,
                '12/09/2013',
                'Jhon Doe',
                'Jhon Doe',
                '450.60$',
                rand(1, 10),
                '<span class="label label-sm label-'.(key($status)).'">'.(current($status)).'</span>',
                '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View</a>',
            );
```

I want add to every table row link, it mean that you can click on datatable row and will be directed to some url, every `row` url will be different (that url I must set). My question is how to set that `row` ulr ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fnRowCallback event of datatable and bind click event to each row.

```
    var oTable = $('#data').dataTable({
          "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {

                // Bind click event
                $(nRow).click(function() {
                      window.open('http://example.com');

                      //OR

                     window.open(aData.url);

                });

                return nRow;
           }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to your detail page (I called it `dataitem.php` for example), and pass the id in the query string:

```
'<a href="dataitem.php?id='.$id.'" class="btn btn-xs default">View</a>'
```

Then, in `dataitem.php`, read the id from the query string so you know which row to display.